# Can Bitcoin Core be used to create a raw transaction for CLAM altcoin?

Tags: altcoin, signature, raw-transaction

Clam is an altcoin that issued that altcoin to the owner of the private key of each and every Bitcoin address that had funds (0.0001 or more) on May 12, 2014.

I don't want to install the Clam client.  If I know the CLAM address that corresponds to my Bitcoin address, and know the Clam txid for the Clam UTXO I can then manually construct the raw transaction. The transaction needs to be signed with the private key but that key in the CLAM client would be the same as the one in my Bitcoin Core wallet for that corresponding Bitcoin address.

So if Bitcoin Core has the private key, can I use it to create the Clam raw transaction?  I know I'ld then need to broadcast the signed raw transaction onto the Clam network but I can do that from another host.

Is this possible?   Or do I need to sign using the Clam client?

Comment: Why did this question get a -1?

Answer (score 1):

No.

CLAM network has another transaction format with additional timestamp field. So, you can not create and sign your transaction with Bitcoin Core client.

Of course, it is possible to create and sign transaction for CLAM network without using untrusted CLAM client software. But you have to have tools to do it besides Bitcoin Core client.

Signing transaction with untrusted software can leak your private key.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I know this is way too late, but for anybody stumbling across this with a Google search: you don't need the Clam client. you just need the private keys for the addresses that contained non-dust amounts at the time of the fork. use a wallet like Coinomi to sweep the private keys, and you're done.